# Where can I find the per-person sprint capacity bars under the New Navigation?

Tags: azure-devops

When enabling the New Navigation preview feature, I can no longer find the per-person sprint capacity bars:

> [image: screenshot of old view]

Have they been moved to another place, or are they removed altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go the "Sprints":

[image]

Click on the "View options" icon and choose "Work details":

[image]

Now you will see it:

[image]